# How can I use nil as empty closure parameter?

Tags: swift3

I have a data loading function that sometimes needs to update the ui via callback:

```
class Middleware {
    ...
    func loadChannels(callback: @escaping (_ middleware: Middleware) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: uri + "/entity.json")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response , error == nil else {
                print("> loadChannels " + error.debugDescription)
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(data: data)

            if (json["entities"].array != nil) {
                self.channels.removeAll()

                for (_, json) in json["entities"] {
                    if let channel = Channel(json: json) {
                        self.channels += [channel]
                    }
                }

                if (callback != nil) {
                    callback!(self)
                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

When I don't need the callback I'm calling it like this:

```
middleware.loadChannels(callback: { (middleware: Middleware) -> Void in })
```

Using

```
middleware.loadChannels(callback: nil)
```

doesn't work:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '(Middleware) -> Void'

Is there a less verbose way than my current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the callback optional:

```
func loadChannels(callback: ((_ middleware: Middleware) -> Void)?) {
}
```

Now you can pass `nil` to the `callback` parameter.

Comment: I had already tried sticking a ? in but didn't realize the additional brackets were needed. Still no go:  @escaping attribute only applies to function types

Comment: Then remove the `@escaping`.

Comment: No chance: Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'callback' may allow it to escape. Catch 22?

Comment: Strange. I don't get that error when I copy and paste this code.

Comment: Funny. Restarted XCode and its happy now- glad to accept as answer, thanks! Much appreciated!